# Plain cascade and Xor cascade

Tags: xor, multiple-encryption

I have seen in few places (mostly papers) talking about plain cascade and XOR cascade. I know what is cascade cipher is but I am not clear about what these are. Can anyone help to understand using simple words to define what is a XOR cascade? (how XOR is involved in cascade cipher?)

Answer (score 2):

Without more context the answer isn't quite precise. In the following answer $\oplus$ always denotes bit-wise XOR.

First let's quickly revisit "plain" cascade encryption. You encrypt arbitrary messages using the keys $K_1,K_2,K_3$ and the encryption algorithm $E$ as follows: $C=E_{K_1}(D_{K_2}(E_{K_3}(P)))$

Now the first possible XOR-cascading construction (more common) is to use three stream-ciphers (or blockciphers in CTR-mode) as follows: $C=E_{K_1}(Ctr)\oplus E_{K_2}(Ctr)\oplus E_{K_3}(Ctr)\oplus P$. This was already recommended by B. Schneier in his *Applied Cryptography*.

The mode, I think is most likely the one you're looking for, is proven secure in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/205.pdf). First you need again the three previously mentioned keys. Secondly you need four more keys of the same length as the blocksize (128-bit for AES-256). Using these additional four keys $l_i$, you encrypt the plaintext $P$ as follows:
$C= E_{K_3}(E_{K_2}(E_{K_1}(P\oplus l_1)\oplus l_2)\oplus l_3)\oplus l_4$.

Comment: I like (and use) XEX type modes, which is essentially $C=E_{K_2}(E_{K_1}(Ctr)\oplus P)\oplus E_{K_{1\ or\ 3}}(Ctr)$

Comment: Is there a security reason (besides It is used in 3DES to allow compatibility with DES) you mention EDE nstead of EEE as the cascade?

Comment: @eckes no security reason, just the same "functional" reasoning as behind 3DES.